# vercel ai - How to confirm onFinish is functioning correctly?

Tags: reactjs, vercel, vercel-ai

I was following rather a complex tutorial https://github.com/tierrun/tier-vercel-openai/blob/main/src/components/app/GenerateSection.tsx but couldn't confirm if the `onFinish` is working as expected.
So now I'm doing a simple logging check using `onFinish`.

```
const {
    completion,
    setCompletion,
    input,
    setInput,
    isLoading,
    handleInputChange,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useCompletion({
    api: "/api/generate2",
    body: {
      model: "gpt-4",
    },
    onFinish: (input: string, completion: string) => {
        console.log(`input: ${input}, completion: ${completion}`);
  }});
```

The code above successfully generates the `completion` and I can render it through html, however, even after the completion, this simple console.log using `onFinish` isn't working.

Can someone point out how to verify `onFinish` is actually working?

Comment: does the console.log() logs an undefined value or it doesnt execute at all?